# how to target parent element only?

Tags: jquery

I've following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="sample-big-product.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
        <span><a href="#">View Product</a></span>
        <ul><li>1,2,3</li></ul>
            <h2>Featured product name</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cosetur adispci elit. Morbi poseure ante porta justo...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="sample-big-product.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
        <span><a href="#">View Product</a></span>
            <ul><li>1,2,3</li></ul>
        <h2>Featured product name</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cosetur adispci elit. Morbi poseure ante porta justo...</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="sample-big-product.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
        <span><a href="#">View Product</a></span>

        <h2>Featured product name</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cosetur adispci elit. Morbi poseure ante porta justo...</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="sample-big-product.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
        <span><a href="#">View Product</a></span>

        <h2>Featured product name</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cosetur adispci elit. Morbi poseure ante porta justo...</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery, so here I target all LI and all UL. But I only want to target ul li and not ul li ul li

```
// get all available UL and LI elements...
var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();

// remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
container.find("UL").remove();
```

p.s. obviously I can simply add .class to them. But I'd rather not complicate markup...

Comment: You cn use child selector. > ul > li

Comment: @undefined that would select children not parent right?

Comment: Yes, it does so. Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: So your que is to target the first "ul" the parent holds other uls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `>` 'direct child of' selector. Assuming `container` is a jQuery object referencing a parent element of the top-level `ul`, this should work:

```
var li_elements = container.find("> ul > li").clone();
container.find("> ul").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only direct descendants of `ul`, use the [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method (assuming `container` is the `ul` element)

```
container.children("li");
```

If you want to select only unordered lists that contain other unordered lists, you can use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector (assuming `container` is an ancestor of `ul`)

```
container.find("ul:has(ul)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted only the first occurrence of ul li and skip the rest then use `first()`.

For example:

```
var li_elements = container.find("LI").first()  // which gives you first li
```

For more info, see: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: He wants all direct descendants, not the first direct descendant.

Comment: @rory ya ,i guess i misunderstood his question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve but as is understood i created a fiddle :

**http://jsfiddle.net/AFM2P/**

in this fiddle i have c`reated a hover event` and `removed the direct children of the hovered ul`

(*`i guess you want to achieve something like this`*)

This is what i have tried:

```
$('ul:first').hover(function(){
    $('ul',this).remove(); //<---------This will remove the child ul 
});                        //           of the hovered ul
```